# SharePoint Add-in deployment on SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-addin, central-administration

My scenario: I have created a SharePoint 2016 farm and i am creating a simple Hello world addin to deploy on my farm.

At first i was deploying the addin using the farm account which i found out later that it is not allowed and i created a second user,whom i gave the collection admin rights and add him to the AD admin group. When i run VS with that second user,i get an error telling me elevated permission is needed.

I can't figure out what to do next. Note this is my first time creating a SharePoint Farm and deploying add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the second user as a local admin and as SharePoint farm admin.
2. Run visual studio as administrator.